# Creatività e dinamismo nella lingua italiana

Tags: history, borrowing, english-comparison

Ogni lingua evolve.

Misurare la creatività di una lingua non è impresa facile, ma l'apparire di neologismi nel lessico ne è un buon estimatore.

Non conosco quale sia la regola dietro la scelta di inserimento di neologismi nel vocabolario (intendendo qui il vocabolario come prodotto editoriale, rivisto periodicamente), e sospetto che non sia universale.

In italiano numerosi neologismi provengono (per ovvi motivi) dall'inglese.
Ci sono sostantivi presi così come sono (e.g., *computer*, *bar*, *pub* ...), e questo non è molto interessante. Più interessante è il caso dei verbi, che se di nuova fattura nell'italiano perché provenienti da fuori prendono sempre la coniugazione in -are (e.g., *cliccare*, *googlare* ...), in parte perché essendo la più diffusa è la più immediata da associare.

L'inserimento di foriesterismi non è l'unico stimolo al dinamismo lessicale. Ci sono infatti neologismi che nascono dall'interno dell'italiano stesso, e famoso è infatti il caso del verbo *perplimere*, nato (anni fa) dalla creatività di un comico. Il suo significato è chiaro e tappa la carenza lessicale di un verbo che significhi "rendere perplesso".
Tuttavia, sebbene siano passati anni, tale verbo non fa ancora parte dei vocabolari ufficiali ([si può leggere la sua storia qui](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/significato-origine-perplimere)).

Questi sono le due categorie principali di dinamismo linguistico che riesco a tracciare nell'italiano. Mi risulta che i dialetti siano molto più creativi, forse perché non avendo un vocabolario scritto non ci si pone il problema sull'inserimento o meno di termini e tutto è lasciato al naturale decorso del parlare. L'italiano ufficiale risulta molto più conservatore nell'accettare il cambiamento.

Chiedo dotti lumi circa la situazione effettiva della lingua in merito al suo dinamismo, anche magari con paragoni con altre lingue. Esempi di termini che siano attualmente in uso ma che abbiano avuto una storia di travagliata accettazione sono particolarmente ben accetti.

Comment: Fra l'altro "perplimere" non sarebbe declinato come "perplesso" ma come "perpliso".

Comment: @Sklivvz come mai?

Comment: Semmai, il verbo “corretto” sarebbe “perplettere” (cf. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/perplesso/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Innanzitutto bisogna fare una distinzione tra **calco** e **prestito**, due fenomeni differenti, i quali poi si suddividono in altri tipi.

Il **calco semantico**, per esempio, aggiunge un significato ad una parola già esistente: realizzare significa anche "rendersi conto" dall'inglese to realize, *salvare* file digitali da to save. Il **calco strutturale** prende una parola straniera e ne riproduce la struttura  più o meno fedelmente traducendo le parole che la compongono; un esempio potrebbe essere *grattacielo - skyscraper*, oppure *loanword - lehnwort*, oppure *fine settimana - weekend*.

Il prestito è invece l'importazione di termini nella propria lingua, ma non solo, vedi il **prestito fonologico** (il suono [ʒ] dal francese, tipo in *garage*). Il prestito si può distinguere poi in:

- **prestito di necessità**: quando si scopre qualcosa di nuovo per cui non esiste un termine
- **prestito di lusso**: termine che esiste già ma viene adottato un termine straniero per via dell'accezione o per dare "pregio" al concetto: *boom di vendite* potrebbe benissimo essere *esplosione di vendite*.
- **prestito non integrato**: viene usato nella forma originaria (anche se poi viene usato come parola neutra), vedi *computer*, *file*, *web*.
- **prestito integrato**: viene modificato per adeguarlo al sistema fono-morfologico della lingua ricevente.

Ma i prestiti che "conosci" o di cui ti accorgi sono solo quelli più recenti. Di moltissimi non è ovvia la natura, per esempio:

- **cifra** attraverso il latino dall'arabo *ṣifr* ‘nulla, zero’
- **gazzella** come sopra dall'arabo *ghazāl*
- **galassia** dal greco *galaksías*, derivato dalla declinazione *gála gálaktos* ‘latte’
- **bistecca** dall'inglese *beef steak*
- **ingaggiare** dal francese antico *engagier*

Un atteggiamento critico verso i prestiti porta al concetto di **forestierismo** ("da fuori"). Ma anche se forse sembra così, l'italiano non è così conservatore, non più di altri comunque. Lo spagnolo presenta molti prestiti integrati, un esempio è *computadora - computer* (chiamato anche *ordenador*). In Francia, l'Académie Française [propone espressioni e/o termini alternativi a quelli inglesi](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/terminologie-et-neologie) per favorire la propria lingua.

Comunque se vuoi leggere di più, ho parlato in precedenza di prestiti in una [mia risposta su Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3071/111).

Comment: Ho scritto un po' di getto, se trovi errori segnalamelo. Domani ricontrollerò la risposta. :)

Comment: By the way, if those who cannot understand italian want a translation, I might provide one.

Comment: Un altro fenomeno interessante correlato con l'importazione di parole e modi di dire è quello del [doppiaggese](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppiaggese).

Answer (score 3):

Inoltre, un termine già esistente può cambiare il significato a causa dell'affermarsi di tendenze politiche o della nascita di una nuova 'moda' (ad es. *scafista* o *girotondo*).

C'è un [bel libro](http://books.google.se/books/about/Parole_nuove_e_datate_Studi_su_neologism.html?id=WRSGkgEACAAJ) di Paolo D'Achille che racconta le storie di alcune parole "nuove", come *bagnoschiuma, fondotinta* e *caffellatte*. E poi Giovanni Petrolini [qui](http://books.google.se/books?id=oCwLAQAAMAAJ) parla di parole dell'uso quotidiano, prese dai dialetti o dalle altre lingue europee (*mortadella, patate, scopa*, ecc.), e delle loro storie più o meno intense, interessanti, ed a volte tragiche.

Comment: Grazie mille dei suggerimenti, comprerò i testi. La mia domanda, più che chiedere notizie su quali neogismi abbiamo, voleva essere mirare a tracciare la situazione organica dell'italiano che ci evolve sotto il naso: come e in che misura. Ho l'impressione che siamo un po' conservatori.

Comment: Siamo un po' conservatori senza dubbio, ma la lingua ha il suo ritmo di evoluzione. Hai visto [quella statistica](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/speciali/italiano_inglese/antonelli.html) degli anglicismi? Non mi sembrano proprio pochi.

Comment: Pochi o tanti non credo che significhi molto. Se si tratta di termini per cui un corrispondente italiano non esiste, è un arricchimento. Altrimenti è un'altra storia (molto complessa da analizzare). In ogni caso sono più interessata ai neologismi di matrice squisitamente italiana, che ai prestiti. Poi vorrei rimarcare che l'inglese ha meno del 30% di vocaboli di origine germanica http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_influence_in_English. Si tratta di un'altra cosa (tempi lunghi, conquiste del apssato...), ma le lingue si parlano tra loro.

Answer (score 2):

Ci sono molti neologismi in italiano, per esempio la [Treccani pubblica una lista in merito](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/neologismi/).

In pratica il linguaggio si evolve in base a mode (come può essere la novità introdotta da un comico), ma anche e soprattutto in base alla necessità di descrivere concetti nuovi.

Vista in quest'ottica, non sorprenderà nessuno che l'evoluzione della lingua italiana sia stimolata da:

- tecnologia (soprattutto sotto forma di neologismi di origine inglese, ma non solo, ad esempio "amicarsi" su Facebook)
- economia e management (anche qui, inglesismi e volgarizzazioni dell'inglese)
- scienza (ad es. "paleoclimatologo")
- giornalismo e politica (per esempio: neo-latinismi come "mattarellum" o "ad personam")

Gli esempi sono molti, il link che ho riportato in testa ne contiene circa un migliaio.