# Quando si può dire che una parola appartiene alla lingua italiana?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary

Pongo questa domanda a partire da un caso pratico.
Provando a rispondere alla domanda [L'espressione 'a fortiori' è italiana o latina?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/lespressione-a-fortiori-e-italiana-o-latina) ho cominciato a consultare il [dizionario Treccani online](http://www.treccani.it/).

In esso l'espressione  "[a fortiori](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/a-fortiori/)" è riportata come appartenente alla lingua italiana con caratteristiche simili ad "[a priori](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/a-priori/)".
Inoltre vi si trova anche "[in vino veritas](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/in-vino-veritas/)", che per la verità è riportata esplicitamente come una espressione latina. Ma "in vino veritas" appartiene alla lingua italiana o no? È di importazione?

Ora, mi rendo conto quanto sia difficile rispondere alla domanda in oggetto poiché la lingua è cosa viva, tuttavia penso si possano delineare alcuni limiti.

Ad esempio lo **Zanichelli** ha dei criteri chiari per decidere [quali siano le parole che devono entrare nel dizionario](http://dizionari.zanichellipro.it/le-parole-dell-anno/pagina-di-esempio/).  (sostanzialmente: se le utilizza il gruppo della 'gente colta').

Anche la [Treccani riporta informazioni interessanti](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/adattamento_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/)...

Tuttavia sono limiti piuttosto vaghi.

Quindi, in coclusione, vorrei fare una doppia domanda:

1. Come si possono stabilire criteri o 'limiti' per cui una parola/espressione appartiene alla lingua italiana
2. Le parole/espressioni straniere inserite nel dizionario, sono da considerarsi italiane? O meglio, si può dire che APPARTENGONO alla lingua italiana? O sono solo di importazione?

Comment: Onestamente, credo che andare a cercare criteri precisi per queste cose sia veramente discutere del sesso degli angeli... La lingua è una realtà talmente fluida e incasinata che qualunque criterio più specifico di "la parola è diffusa tra i parlanti" sarà comunque estremamente arbitrario e soggetto più che altro al buonsenso di chi lo applica.

Comment: «… E avrai dei figli da una donna strana | E che non parlano l'Italiano» «Ma mamma io per dirti il vero | L'Italiano non so cosa sia | E pure se attraverso il mondo | Non conosco la geografia …» (cit.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La parola computer è un prestito ma ormai è la parola standard in Italiano quando ci si riferisce agli oggetti tecnologici, eppure una parola corrispettiva italiana esiste: *calcolatore*. In questo caso parliamo di un prestito non integrato di lusso. Puoi vedere cosa significhino questi termini [in una mia risposta precedente](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1158/57).

Quello a cui voglio arrivare però è che se una parola viene usata comunemente, che sia palesemente di origine straniera o meno non è il fattore discriminante, ma il fatto che viene usata estensivamente. Dico palesemente poi perché moltissime parole che tu pensi italiane hanno origine da prestiti. Vedi la parola cifra per esempio, o gazzella.

Per questo motivo non si può parlare di parole "straniere" in questo senso, e come hai detto tu, la lingua è viva, si evolve. L'unico criterio che ti resta è, il termine viene usato comunemente da una buona porzione della popolazione?

Anche se di solito le persone prendono il dizionario come base per poter usare parole, è meno noto il fatto che è anche vero il contrario: il dizionario aggiunge, rimuove o modifica lemmi e significati in base all'uso dei madrelingua. Per esempio, la parola computer è presente nel dizionario, questo la rende una parola "italiana", ma è stata aggiunta di conseguenza al fatto che viene usata da praticamente la totalità della popolazione. Gli italiani non hanno usato computer perché lo hanno visto scritto nel dizionario, quindi il criterio rimane sempre il fatto che un termine sia usato dalla maggioranza e in modo continuato.

Comment: Sì, però talune semplificazioni della lingua sembrano davvero eccessive; e se dovesse continuare questo *trend* saremo costretti a distinguere concretamente, come credo pensi John Lawler, l'italiano scritto da quello parlato.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis A quali semplificazioni ti riferisci?

Comment: Per esempio, ormai sempre più spesso sento dire 'qual'è il tuo *punto*?' invece di 'qual'è il tuo *punto di vista?*'. Questi sono fatti sintomatologici di una grave decadenza della lingua.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Ma quella non è una semplificazione, la prima espressione è come quando dici "il punto della situazione", quindi "qual è il tuo punto" sarebbe "cosa vuoi dire/qual è la tua posizione". Invece "qual è il tuo punto di vista" è "qual è la tua opinione". Non vedo semplificazioni, ma anche se ci fosse, non capisco perché pensi sia una grave decadenza.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Un'altra cosa: su cosa commentavi della mia risposta nel tuo primo commento?

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Secondo me _qual è il tuo punto?_ ha origine dal tradurre letteralmente l'inglese _What's your point?_; la mia impressione è che qui _il tuo punto_ non stia per _il tuo punto di vista_ bensì qualcosa tipo _qual è il concetto_, o _la conclusione della tua osservazione_, che secondo me è il significato dell'inglese _your point_ . Da Italiano che vive all'estero e usa l'inglese nella quotidianità,mi sono sorpreso spesso ad usare (probabilmente erroneamente) l'espressione _il tuo punto_ dove in inglese si direbbe _your point_. Lo vedo succedere anche ad altri Italiani all'estero.

Answer (score 0):

Credo che l'appartenenza di una parola  a qualunque lingua sia meglio espressa mediante criteri di tipo statistico (oppure con logiche fuzzy) piuttosto che con criteri binari sì / no. Mentre esistono parole (in senso lato) che sono chiaramente italiane (allorquando) o non italiane (serendipity), esiste tutta una zona di incertezza proprio perché, come giustamente hai osservato, la lingua è una cosa viva. Il tentativo di normare regole di appartenenza, benché interessante, è destinato a essere una forzatura con speranze di successo nulle. Provocatoriamente: qualunquemente è una parola della lingua italiana? Verrebbe da dire di no eppure è assai più usata (576.000 risultati su Google) della parola ipostasi (53.600 risultati) o del termine: invarianza (312.000 risultati). Assai empiricamente penso che l'uso di Google (numero di documenti trovati), che a volte è dirimente per stabilire la grafia di parole di altre lingue, possa essere un criterio non insensato per valutare l'appartenenza di una parola alla lingua italiana.

Nel caso specifico aggiungerei una osservazione. L'appartenenza linguistica non è un dato a priori: è un contesto; e, a mio modestissimo parere, l'uso di "a fortiori" da parte di parlanti italiani non rende la parola più latina per il semplice fatto che ci sono stati dei parlanti latini a usarla. In altre parole origine e uso sono due cose ben distinte.

Comment: Daniel grazie della risposta, aggiunge elementi importanti. Attenzione però all'uso di Google. Credo sia solo uno degli elementi (non il principale) per verificare l'uso di un lemma, o di una espressione, e anche forse un po' improprio poichè il linguaggio del web non è il linguaggio parlato e nemmeno quello scritto sui libri... insomma la questione è complessa, e Google isn't God. :)

Comment: Sono d'accordo: Google non è un oracolo e sono conscio dei suoi limiti. ma volevo evidenziare l'importanza di un atteggiamento empirico e realistico. Quandi studenti, anche del liceo classico, consultano in casa il grande dizionario enciclopedico della lingua italiana e quanti invece fanno ricerche su Google? Forse è in questo contesto che la tua domanda, che ha illustri precedenti, può assumere significati particolarmente interessanti.